# Export Access table to SP with display control Combo box

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, microsoft-access, vba

I have table in MS Access, that has following lookup properties:
Display control: Combobox
Row source type: Value list
Row source: "Option 1";"Option 2";"Option 3"

And I want export this table to Sharepoint. When I use export from Access (External data, more, Sharepoint) this field works on SP without problem. But I need to use VBA and with following code:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "WSS", _
 "http://spsite", _
 acTable, "tbFromSP", "exportedTable"
```

field loses this choices and acts like normal text field. Is somehow possible to run export through VBA and not loose this options?

Answer (score 0):

I think Lookups in SharePoint are more like #1;Choice1;#2;Choice2; etc so that might be a cause. Let me know if you have already solved this and how you did it.

Comment: I have completely changed the previous code. I used export from Access and saved it. Using VBA, I change XML of this saved export (Access.CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(0).XML) and run  DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport.